# java Scanner.hasNext always false

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In my code method scanner.hasNext() always give false result. I understood it when debugged code. Anybody know what a problem? I checked file. File starts with Strings.

```
public class TextFileImplementor {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.println("Enter the name of file\n");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File(scanner.nextLine());
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (scanner.hasNext()){
                stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            String [] strings = stringBuilder.toString().split("\\. ");
            File newFile = new File("new_" + file.getName());
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile, true);
            for (String string :
                    strings) {
                if (string.length()<141){
                    fileWriter.write(string + "\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the file is empty?

Comment: If you're going to call `scanner.nextLine()`, check with `scanner.hasNextLine()`. Probably not the issue, though.

Comment: @AndyTurner, changed to scanner.hasNextLine(). The problem is not resolved.

Comment: When I debug your code, it reads lines in the file just fine.  Take another look at your output code and/or the contents of your input file.

Comment: @azurefrog , now i trying with different files and sometimes its work. I guess it problems with encoding, i will try to resolve it. But data dont writing into output file. and i dont understand why.

Comment: @azurefrog , resolved. I had to add .flush and .close

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem isn't in the code that's shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved! I had problems with encoding of input file. And i had to add

```
fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```